# Select from a table who is all available in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently working on some sql tables, Here is the tables below in an image.

#### Sailors

| sid | sname | rating | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | Dustin | 7 | 45.0 |
| 29 | Brutus | 1 | 33.0 |
| 31 | Lubber | 8 | 55.5 |
| 32 | Andy | 8 | 25.5 |
| 58 | Rusty | 10 | 35.0 |
| 64 | Horatio | 7 | 35.0 |
| 71 | Zorba | 10 | 16.0 |
| 74 | Horatio | 9 | 35.0 |
| 85 | Art | 3 | 25.5 |
| 95 | Bob | 3 | 63.5 |

#### Reserves

| sid | bid | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 101 | 10/10/98 |
| 22 | 102 | 10/10/98 |
| 22 | 103 | 10/8/98 |
| 22 | 104 | 10/7/98 |
| 31 | 102 | 11/10/98 |
| 31 | 103 | 11/6/98 |
| 31 | 104 | 11/12/98 |
| 64 | 101 | 9/5/98 |
| 64 | 102 | 9/8/98 |
| 74 | 103 | 9/8/98 |

#### Boats

| bid | bname | bcolor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Interlake | blue |
| 102 | Interlake | red |
| 103 | Clipper | green |
| 104 | Marine | red |

So, I want to select a person in table Sailors who had reserved all boats from table boats, which is Dustin.

My first thought on the code is

```
SELECT s.sname 
FROM Sailors s, Reserves r, Boats b 
WHERE s.sid=r.sid AND r.bid=b.bid AND b.color='red' AND b.color='green' AND b.color='blue';
```

But, the function above will keep increasing if I add the new boats with a different colors.

My question is, are there any shorter way to call the person without stating the boat one by one? Is there any shorter version to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you actually tried your first thought?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it, on MariaDB.

Comment: See how I edited the boats table? Please take a few minutes to edit your question so the other samples follow the same convention. Images of data are **NEVER** a good option here. It makes it harder for us to help you, and therefore less likely you'll get a good, fast answer. Even better if you can use a site like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)  or [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to prepare the schema in advance. Again, this will tend to make it so you get a good answer much faster.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn how do I do that? is it by | col1 | col2 | col3 | or external software? any links?

Comment: @Al_Muzakier No external software. Use the edit button on the question and you will be able to see how I formatted your sample. Fix the other samples to match, and then save the edit. You can copy/paste out of your original data to make this faster.

Comment: I see the edit. Well done, it earned an upvote from me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```
SELECT r.sid
FROM Reserves r
GROUP BY r.sid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.bid) = 
    (select count(distinct bid) from boats)
```

What we're doing is matching the count of total unique boats registered for each sailor with the count of total boats possible. If you need more than just the `sid` value you can JOIN back to the `Sailors` table again.

*Do **NOT** use the old `FROM A,B` join syntax for this,* as you did in the original question. That syntax has been *obsolete* for more than 25 years now. Today, you should pretty much **always** specify the `JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I'd take would be to select all `sid` values from `table_reserves` that have a distinct count of `bid` equal to the rowcount of the `boats` table. I don't have your schema prepared, but it'd be something like this:

```
with cte AS (

    SELECT 
    sid, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT bid) AS unique_boat_count

    FROM reserves r

    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bid) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM boats
        )
)       
select 

s.sname

FROM cte 

INNER JOIN sailors s
    ON s.sid = cte.sid
```